# Microsoft visual studio 2015 visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am having a problem with Microsoft Visual Studio (the newest one). During my lessons at the university we use very, very old version of MSV (we still have Windows XP on computers at my uni). I have some homework to do, so I downloaded the newest version right away, and wanted to use a sample graphics project for c++ to make a sinus function chart. Unfortunately, the sample project I am using is not compatible with new MSV. After loading it i got a lot of messages with errors. Nonetheless, I decided to run a sample program, and of course I received an error - `"/....path.../ is not recognized as external or internal command, operable program or batch file"`. Is there any way to make this sample graphics project operational? If no, could you recommend me any guides how to make one? (I couldn't find any).
Cheers and thank you for your replies!

> Migration Report - projekt
>   projekt.vcproj: VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool is no longer supported. The tool has been removed from your project settings.
>
> projekt.vcproj: Attribute 'Detect64BitPortabilityProblems' of 'VCCLCompilerTool' is not supported in this version and has been removed during conversion.
>
> projekt.vcproj: Attribute 'Detect64BitPortabilityProblems' of 'VCCLCompilerTool' is not supported in this version and has been removed during conversion.
>
> projekt.vcproj: All user macros reported below for configuration 'Debug|Win32' are used before their definition, which can cause undesirable build results; this is not supported in this release. You can resolve this by changing the inclusion order of the consuming property sheets and making sure they come after the property sheets defining the user macros.
>
> projekt.vcproj: MSB4211: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Common.props (128,5); The property "WindowsTargetPlatformVersion" is being set to a value for the first time, but it was already consumed at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.props (29,5)".
>
> projekt.vcproj: All user macros reported below for configuration 'Release|Win32' are used before their definition, which can cause undesirable build results; this is not supported in this release. You can resolve this by changing the inclusion order of the consuming property sheets and making sure they come after the property sheets defining the user macros.
>
> projekt.vcproj: MSB4211: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Common.props (128,5); The property "WindowsTargetPlatformVersion" is being set to a value for the first time, but it was already consumed at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.props (29,5)".
>
> projekt.vcproj: MSB8012: $(TargetName) ('Grafika') does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value 'Debug\WinBGI.exe' ('WinBGI') in project configuration 'Debug|Win32'. This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(TargetName) property value matches the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
>
> projekt.vcproj: MSB8012: $(TargetPath) ('C:\Breslerek\Visual Studio Projects\Projekt\Debug\Grafika.exe') does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value 'Debug\WinBGI.exe' ('C:\Breslerek\Visual Studio Projects\Projekt\Debug\WinBGI.exe') in project configuration 'Debug|Win32'. This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(TargetPath) property value matches the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
>
> projekt.vcproj: MSB8012: $(TargetName) ('Grafika') does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value 'Release\WinBGI.exe' ('WinBGI') in project configuration 'Release|Win32'. This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(TargetName) property value matches the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
>
> projekt.vcproj: MSB8012: $(TargetPath) ('C:\Breslerek\Visual Studio Projects\Projekt\Release\Grafika.exe') does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value 'Release\WinBGI.exe' ('C:\Breslerek\Visual Studio Projects\Projekt\Release\WinBGI.exe') in project configuration 'Release|Win32'. This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(TargetPath) property value matches the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
>
> projekt.vcproj: Converting project file 'C:\Breslerek\Visual Studio Projects\Projekt\projekt.vcproj'.
>
> projekt.vcproj: Done converting to new project file 'C:\Breslerek\Visual Studio Projects\Projekt\projekt.vcxproj'.
>
> projekt.sln: Visual Studio needs to make non-functional changes to this project in order to enable the project to open in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without impacting project behavior.
>
> projekt.sln: File successfully backed up as C:\Breslerek\Visual Studio Projects\Projekt\Backup\projekt.sln
>
> projekt.sln: Solution migrated successfully

Comment: Which graphics library are we talking about?

Comment: Visual c++ I think :)

Comment: That's not a graphics library. It's an IDE & build env.

Comment: Also, please paste the errors you're getting.

Comment: Post the error messages as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Ok, done. So, I am quite new to graphics in programming, so that's where my lack of knowledge of libraries stems from. I posted errors now as a text :)

Comment: There have been a lot of changes in VS between 2005/2008 and the latest versions.  It is mainly to do with filenames as you've found out.  If you just want a simple old fashioned graphics project, create a win32 or MFC application.  If you want a newer fancy one, create a .net one but for that, you'd actually be better off using either C# or VB.net.

Comment: Wild guess: Go to *`Project -> Configuration Properties -> Platform Toolset`* and select *`Visual Studio 2015 (v140)`* if not already selected, rebuild the project.

Comment: With respect to the $(TargetName) error, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650993/how-to-set-outdir-targetname-targetext-and-lib-outputfile-with-vi/44265324#44265324