# Is it possible to have a different File Name when using Debug compilation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm compiling a .dll file and wonder if there's a posibillity to create a different Name for my .dll File if it's compiled in Debug mode.

Currently the Name of the .dll is the Solution name itself.
If I compile on Debug mode, I would like to name my file "SolutionName_Debug.dll"

Thanks for every reply.

Comment: Yes this is entirely possible. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650993/how-to-set-outdir-targetname-targetext-and-lib-outputfile-with-vi) might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *Project* -> *Properties* -> *General* -> *Target Name* and set it to *SolutionName_Debug* without the *.dll* part. Make sure you are in the *Debug* configuration.

[image]